# AES GCM encryption and decryption: PHP VS C# BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, php, aes, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

I am currently working on transforming my C# AES-GCM cryptography code to PHP. However, after some research, the text encrypted by my PHP system cannot be decrypted by the C# one. I want to know if there is any difference from both codes:

C# with BouncyCastle:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

//the helper for all AES methods
public class AESHelper {

    private const int KEY_BIT_SIZE = 256;
    private const int MAC_BIT_SIZE = 128;
    private const int NONCE_BIT_SIZE = 128;

    private readonly SecureRandom random;

    private static AESHelper instance;
    public static AESHelper Instance //property of this class. Create an instance if it is not created yet
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new AESHelper();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public AESHelper()
    {
        random = new SecureRandom();
    }

    //decrypt with strings
    public string Decrypt(string message, string key, int nonSecretPayloadLength = 0)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            throw new ArgumentException("Message required!", "message");
        var decodedKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
        var cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(message);
        var plainText = DecryptWithKey(cipherText, decodedKey, nonSecretPayloadLength);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
    }

    //encrypt with strings
    public string Encrypt(string text, string key, byte[] nonSecretPayload = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            throw new ArgumentException("Text required!", "text");
        var decodedKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
        var plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var cipherText = EncryptWithKey(plainText, decodedKey, nonSecretPayload);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }

    //create new key
    public string NewKey()
    {
        var key = new byte[KEY_BIT_SIZE / 8];
        random.NextBytes(key);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(key);
    }

    //decrypt with byte array
    private byte[] DecryptWithKey(byte[] message, byte[] key, int nonSecretPayloadLength = 0)
    {
        if (key == null || key.Length != KEY_BIT_SIZE / 8)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Key needs to be {0} bit!", KEY_BIT_SIZE), "key");
        if (message == null || message.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Message required!", "message");

        using (var cipherStream = new MemoryStream(message))
            using (var cipherReader = new BinaryReader(cipherStream))
        {
            var nonSecretPayload = cipherReader.ReadBytes(nonSecretPayloadLength);
            var nonce = cipherReader.ReadBytes(NONCE_BIT_SIZE / 8);
            var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
            var parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), MAC_BIT_SIZE, nonce, nonSecretPayload);
            cipher.Init(false, parameters);
            var cipherText = cipherReader.ReadBytes(message.Length - nonSecretPayloadLength - nonce.Length);
            var plainText = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(cipherText.Length)];
            try
            {
                var len = cipher.ProcessBytes(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length, plainText, 0);
                cipher.DoFinal(plainText, len);
            }
            catch (InvalidCipherTextException)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return plainText;
        }
    }

    //encrypt with byte array
    private byte[] EncryptWithKey(byte[] text, byte[] key, byte[] nonSecretPayload = null)
    {
        if (key == null || key.Length != KEY_BIT_SIZE / 8)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Key needs to be {0} bit!", KEY_BIT_SIZE), "key");

        nonSecretPayload = nonSecretPayload ?? new byte[] { };
        var nonce = new byte[NONCE_BIT_SIZE / 8];
        random.NextBytes(nonce, 0, nonce.Length);
        var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
        var parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(key), MAC_BIT_SIZE, nonce, nonSecretPayload);
        cipher.Init(true, parameters);
        var cipherText = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(text.Length)];
        var len = cipher.ProcessBytes(text, 0, text.Length, cipherText, 0);
        cipher.DoFinal(cipherText, len);
        using (var combinedStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(combinedStream))
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(nonSecretPayload);
                binaryWriter.Write(nonce);
                binaryWriter.Write(cipherText);
            }
            return combinedStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the PHP system:

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';

    $hash_string = 'qIANSOwtdfF4y5Yk33ZLE5s6KwKBAeu6qzJRG84Sjjo=';
    echo "password : ";
    var_dump($hash_string);
    echo '<hr>';
    $decode_string = base64_decode($hash_string);
    $app_cc_aes_key = substr($decode_string, 0, 32);
    $cipher = 'aes-256-gcm';
    $iv_len = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    echo "app_cc_aes_key : ";
    var_dump($app_cc_aes_key);
    echo '<br>';
    echo "cipher :";
    var_dump($cipher);
    echo '<hr>';

    $data = '7bc9d6ae-982f-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64';
    echo "data : {$data}";
    echo '<hr>';

    $tag_length = 16;
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_len);
    $tag = "";
    $encrypt = openssl_encrypt($data, $cipher, $app_cc_aes_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag, "", $tag_length);
    $encrypt_text = base64_encode($iv.$tag.$encrypt);
    echo "encrypt :";
    var_dump($encrypt);
    echo '<br>';
    echo "encrypt_text :";
    var_dump($encrypt_text);
    echo '<hr>';

    $decoded_text = base64_decode($encrypt_text);
    $iv = substr($decoded_text, 0, $iv_len);
    $tag = substr($decoded_text, $iv_len, $tag_length);
    $ciphertext = substr($decoded_text, $iv_len + $tag_length);
    $decrypt_text = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $app_cc_aes_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
    echo "decrypt_text : {$decrypt_text}";
    echo '<hr>';
?>
```

Can anyone tell me if there is something missing or different in the PHP code that makes them done differently? Or if there is some internal difference between the PHP functions and the BouncyCastle functions that make them different?

Comment: *the text ... cannot be decrypted by the C# ...* This is not a useful description of the problem. What exactly is the error? Is there an exception? If so, include the full information in the exception. Is the decryption proceeding but the result is not what you expected? If so, explain what happened and what you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In the C#-code, the data are concatenated in the following order during encryption:

  `nonSecretPyload` `nonce` `cipherText`

  Here `cipherText` consists of two parts, the encrypted message and the authentication tag. Appending the tag to the encrypted message is done automatically by [`GcmBlockCipher#DoFinal`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/GCMBlockCipher.html#doFinal-byte:A-int-).

  In the PHP-code, the data are concatenated in the following order during encryption:

  `$iv` `$tag` `$encrypt`

  Here `$iv` is the counterpart to `nonce`. In contrast to `GcmBlockCipher#DoFinal`, the PHP-method [`openssl_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) returns only the encrypted message (`$encrypt`). The authentication tag is returned in a separate variable (6th `openssl_encrypt`-parameter `$tag`). Therefore, `$tag` and `$encrypt` correspond in reverse order to `cipherText`. The *additional authenticated data*, i.e. the counterpart to `nonSecretPyload` are not considered in the PHP-code at all.

  It is immediately apparent that the orders of the individual components in the two codes are different. This means that a message encrypted in the C#-code cannot be decrypted in the PHP-code (and vice versa). For this to be possible, the order in the PHP-code must be changed as follows:

  `$aad` `$iv` `$encrypt` `$tag`

  Here `$aad` is the counterpart to `nonSecretPyload`. The order (as well the consideration of the additional authenticated data) must be adapted both in the encryption part and in the decryption part.
- In addition, different IV lengths are used: In the C#-code 16 bytes, in the PHP-code 12 bytes (the latter because `openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-gcm')` returns `12`), where 12 bytes is actually the [recommended length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010599/9014097). For compatibility, a uniform IV length must be used in both codes!