# Decrypt AES-GCM in php : Convert Javascript code?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, cryptography, cryptojs

I have a function that decrypt AES-GCM encrypted text in Javascript.
I would like to make it work in Php, so I can decipher messages sent by Javascript.

I have two functions: the first one imports and derives a password to a CryptoKey (with salt), the second one uses the CryptoKey to decipher the encrypted message.

```
    async importAESGCMKeyFromPassword(password, salt){
        const enc = new TextEncoder()

        const keyMaterial = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
            'raw', 
            enc.encode(password), 
            { name: 'PBKDF2' }, 
            false, 
            ['deriveBits', 'deriveKey']
        )

        return window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
            {
                'name': 'PBKDF2',
                salt: Buffer.from(salt, 'base64'), 
                'iterations': 1000,
                'hash': 'SHA-256'
            },
            keyMaterial,
            { 'name': 'AES-GCM', 'length': 256},
            true,
            [ 'encrypt', 'decrypt' ]
        )
    },
    
    async decryptAESGCM(key, iv, message){
        if( typeof message != 'string' ) return null
        let result
        try{
            result = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
                {
                    name: 'AES-GCM',
                    iv: Buffer.from(iv, 'base64')
                },
                key,
                Buffer.from(message, 'base64')
            )
        }catch(error){
            return null
        }
        const dec = new TextDecoder()
        return dec.decode(result)
    },
```

How can I convert them in php code ?

I tried this way [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930881/decrypting-a-string-encrypted-by-php-with-aes256-gcm-using-openssl-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com) But it does not seems to work...

Comment: Post your PHP code and describe the problem. Also share some test data.

Comment: Done, just updated

Comment: Just a quick shot - in Js you are running 100000 iterations and in PHP its 1000 only...

Comment: The test data cannot be decrypted with the JavaScript code. Complete the posted JavaScript code so that we can verify that this data is indeed decryptable with the JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated iterations count, and figured out the default tag size was 128 bits, so I updated the code to show the working one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the php code that seems to work :

```
$encrypted = base64_decode($encrypted);
$salt = base64_decode($salt);
$iv = base64_decode($iv);
$key = hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $password, $salt, 1000, 256/8, true);
$tag = substr($encrypted, -16, 16);
$encrypted = substr($encrypted, 0, -16);
return openssl_decrypt($encrypted, 'aes-256-gcm', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
```